# Converting from c name sorting code to NASM assembly code crashes

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, nasm

I am trying to convert a given c code that sorts names in a given txt file into NASM assembly code. I implemented the c code, line by line and it does build without error; however, when i run it, it crashes.
This is working c code to sort names in .txt file 'names.txt' :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char path[]="names.txt";

  char szName[50];

  int count=0;

  int size=0;

  int x=0;
  int y=0;

  char* temp=0;
  int pos=0;

  FILE* file=fopen(path,"rt");

  if (file){

  while (!feof(file)){

  fscanf(file,"%50s",szName);
  count++;


  }

  }
  else{
       printf("Error opening file\n");
       return 1;
  }

  printf ("Count: %d\n",count);

  char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));

  rewind(file);

  count=0;



  while (!feof(file)){

  fscanf(file,"%50s",szName);

  size=strlen(szName);

  names[count]=(char*)malloc(size+1);

  strcpy(names[count],szName);

  count++;


  }

  printf("Original file\n");

  for (x=0;x<count;x++){

  printf("Name %d:\t%s\n",x+1,names[x]);

  }


  for (x=0;x<count;x++){

  temp=names[x];
  pos=x;

  for (y=x;y<count;y++){

      if (strcmp(temp,names[y])>0){

      temp=names[y];
      pos=y;

      }    
  }

  temp=names[x];
  names[x]=names[pos];
  names[pos]=temp;    
  }

  printf("Sorted names\n");

  for (x=0;x<count;x++){

  printf("Name %d:\t%s\n",x+1,names[x]);

  }

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my implementation of this c code in NASM assembly:

```
extern _scanf
extern _printf
extern _fopen
extern _rewind
extern _fscanf
extern _fprintf
extern _malloc
extern _free
extern _strcpy
extern _strcmp
extern _feof
extern _strlen
extern _system
extern _fclose

segment .data

szFname db 'names.txt',0
szName TIMES 50 db 0
szMode db 'rt',0
szIn db '%49s',0
szOut db 'Name %d: %s',10,0
szError db 'Could not open file: %s',10,0
szCount db 'Count: %d',10,0
szPause db 'PAUSE',0
szOriginal db 'Original file\n',0
szSorted db 'Sorted names\n',0


segment .code

global _main
_main:

%define count [ebp-4]
%define size [ebp-8]
%define x [ebp-12]
%define y [ebp-16]
%define temp [ebp-20]
%define pos [ebp-24]
%define file [ebp-28]
%define names [ebp-32]

enter 32,0
;int main(int argc, char *argv[]]

;charpath[]="names.txt";

;char szName[50];

;int count=0; 
;int size=0;
;int x=0;
;int y=0;
;char* temp=0;
;int pos=0;
mov dword count,0
mov dword size,0
mov dword x,0
mov dword y,0 
mov dword temp,0
mov dword pos,0

;FILE* file=fopen(path,"rt");
push dword szMode
push szFname ;PATH
call _fopen
add esp, 8
mov dword file, eax


;if (file){
cmp dword file,0 ;NO WAY IN HELL THIS IS RIGHT
jne _noFile

; while (!feof(file)){
_while1begin:

push dword file  
call _feof
add esp,4
cmp eax,0
je _while1end

;  fscanf(file,"%50s",szName);
push dword szName
push dword szIn
push dword file
call _fscanf
add esp,12

;  count++;}}
inc dword count
jmp _while1begin

;else{
; printf("Error opening file\n");
_noFile:
push dword szError
call _printf
add esp,4

_while1end:

;printf ("Count: %d\n",count);
push dword count
push dword szCount
call _printf
add esp,8

;char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));

;rewind(file);
push dword file
call _rewind
add esp,4

;count=0;
mov dword count,0

;while (!feof(file)){
_while2begin:
push dword file  
call _feof
add esp,4
cmp eax,0
je _while2end

; fscanf(file,"%50s",szName);
push dword szName
push dword szIn
push dword file
call _fscanf
add esp, 12

; size=strlen(szName);
push dword szName
call _strlen
add esp,4
mov dword size,eax

; names[count]=(char*)malloc(size+1);
mov ebx, size
inc ebx
push ebx
call _malloc
add esp,4
mov ebx, dword names
mov ecx, dword count
mov [ebx+ecx], eax

; strcpy(names[count],szName);
mov ebx, dword names
mov ecx, dword count
push dword szName
push dword [ebx+ecx]
call _strcpy
add esp,8


; count++;}
inc dword count
jmp _while2begin

_while2end:

;printf("Original file\n");
push dword szOriginal
call _printf
add esp,4

;for (x=0;x<count;x++){
mov dword x, 0
_for1begin:
mov ebx, dword x
mov ecx, dword count
cmp ebx, ecx
jge _for1end
; printf("Name %d:\t%s\n",x+1,names[x]);}
mov ebx, dword names
mov ecx, dword count
mov eax, [ebx+ecx]

push eax
mov ebx,x
inc ebx
push ebx
push dword szOut
call _printf
add esp,12

inc dword count
jmp _for1begin

_for1end:  
mov dword x, 0
;for (x=0;x<count;x++){
_for2begin:
mov ebx, dword x
mov ecx, dword count
cmp ebx, ecx
jge _for2end
; temp=names[x];
mov ebx, dword x
mov ecx, dword names
lea eax, [ebx+ecx]
mov temp, eax
; pos=x;
mov dword pos, ebx
; y=x;
mov dword y, ebx

; while (y<count){
_while3begin:
mov ebx, dword y
mov ecx, dword count
cmp ebx, ecx
jge _while3end

;  if (strcmp(temp,names[y])>0){
mov ebx, dword y
mov ecx, dword names
mov edx, [ebx+ecx]
push edx
call _strcmp
add esp,4
cmp eax, 0  
jle _if1end  
;   temp=names[y];
mov ebx, dword y
mov ecx, dword names
lea eax, [ebx+ecx]
mov temp, eax
;   pos=y;}
mov dword pos, ebx
_if1end:
;   y++}
inc dword y
_while3end:

; temp=names[x];
mov ebx, dword x
mov ecx, dword names
lea eax, [ebx+ecx]
mov temp, eax
; names[x]=names[pos];
mov ebx, dword pos
mov ecx, dword names
mov eax, [ebx+ecx]

mov ebx, dword x
mov ecx, dword names
mov [ebx+ecx], eax
; names[pos]=temp;}
mov ebx, dword pos
mov ecx, dword names
mov eax, temp
mov dword [ebx+ecx], eax
_for2end:

;printf("Sorted names\n");
push dword szSorted
call _printf
add esp,4

;x=0;
mov dword x,0
;while (x<count){
_while4begin:

mov ebx, dword x
mov ecx, dword count
cmp ebx,ecx
jge _while4end

; printf("Name %d:\t%s\n",x+1,names[x]);
mov ebx, dword x
mov ecx, dword names
push dword [ebx+ecx]
push dword [ebx+1]
push dword szOut
call _printf
add esp,12
; x++}
inc dword x

_while4end:

;system("PAUSE");
push dword szPause
call_system
add esp,4


leave
ret
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: "I implemented the c code, ... it does build without error; ... it crashes." seems a bit orthogonal to  "This is working c code" - unless the purpose of the code is to crash... It either is working code or it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `malloc` your `names` array; implement

```
;char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));
```

Also, `count` is incremented with `1`, but the array entries are pointer-sized; you'll want to multiply `count` by 4 when accessing the `names` array. Change this block:

```
; strcpy(names[count],szName);
mov ebx, dword names
mov ecx, dword count
push dword szName
push dword [ebx+ecx]              
call _strcpy
add esp,8
```

to

```
mov ebx, dword names
mov ecx, dword count
lea ebx, [ebx + ecx * 4]
push dword szName
push dword [ebx]
call _strcpy
add esp,8
```

There might be other problems, though..

Comment: Thank you for this, but it still crashes. apparently more stuff is wrong.

Comment: You implemented that quickly ;-) It's debugging time - simplify your code: open and close the file first, commenting out what's in between. Then incrementally re-enable portions to find out what is causing the problem. Or perhaps use a debugger?